# Mutate - NA Handling

Tags: r, dplyr, na, mutated

I've used the arrange and mutate combination to do additions based on groupings.  For example, I've used the following:

```
master_df <-group_by(master_df,asof_dt)
mutate(master_df,tot_flag=ls_flag)
```

This groups my data frame master_df by asof_dt, and then creates tot_flag and adds ls_flag by date.

However, my ls_flag column contains NA's.

I would like to do the following:
1)  find out how to add the ls_flag, ignoring any NA's
2)  find out how to add the total number of NA's per day.

Here is the full example:

```
asof_dt<-c("2014-10-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-02","2014-10-02","2014-10-02")
ls_flag<-c(1,1,NA,NA,1,1)
master_df<-data.frame(asof_dt,ls_flag)
master_df <-group_by(master_df,asof_dt)
mutate(master_df,tot_flag=sum(ls_flag))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your problem & data.

Comment: Thank you.  I added it to the original example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this your desired result? You can use the `na.rm = TRUE` option in `sum()`:

```
master_df %>%
  group_by(asof_dt) %>%
  mutate(tot_flag = sum(ls_flag, na.rm = TRUE),
         tot_NA = sum(is.na(ls_flag)))

#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#Groups: asof_dt
#
#     asof_dt ls_flag tot_flag tot_NA
#1 2014-10-01       1        2      1
#2 2014-10-01       1        2      1
#3 2014-10-01      NA        2      1
#4 2014-10-02      NA        2      1
#5 2014-10-02       1        2      1
#6 2014-10-02       1        2      1
```

Or perhaps you just want a "summary" (using `summarise`):

```
master_df %>%
  group_by(asof_dt) %>%
  summarise(tot_flag = sum(ls_flag, na.rm = TRUE),
            tot_NA = sum(is.na(ls_flag)))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#
#     asof_dt tot_flag tot_NA
#1 2014-10-01        2      1
#2 2014-10-02        2      1
```

Comment: Yes thank you.  Looks like for some function the na.rm is nested inside, and for others, it's outside.  I should have checked the PDF now that I see it in there.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

For sum:

```
> aggregate(ls_flag~asof_dt, data=master_df, sum)
     asof_dt ls_flag
1 2014-10-01       2
2 2014-10-02       2
```

or:

```
> with(master_df, tapply(ls_flag, asof_dt, sum, na.rm=T))
2014-10-01 2014-10-02 
         2          2
```

For count of NAs:

```
> with(master_df, tapply(ls_flag, asof_dt, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
2014-10-01 2014-10-02 
         1          1
```